# Not able to upload a file to Rails server with Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, angular-file-upload

So I am using the `gem 'angular-file-upload-rails'` which installs me this Angular plugin: [Angular File Ipload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Now the code I am using currently to upload my file looks like this:

HTML:

```
<form ng-controller="MediumNewCtrl">
    <input type="file" ng-file-select="upload2($files)" multiple>
</form>
```

Coffescript:

```
$scope.upload2 = ($file) ->
        console.log($file[0])
        fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer($file[0])
        fileReader.onload = (e) ->
            $upload.http(
                url: "/media.json"
                headers: 'Content-Type': $file[0].type
                data: medium: {text: 'text', image_video: e.target.result}
            ).progress((evt) ->
                console.log "percent: " + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)
                return
            ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
                # file is uploaded successfully
                console.log data

            ).error((data) ->
                console.log 'Error'
            )
```

And now when I look at what my server responded, I see this:

```
Started POST "/media.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-12 20:19:10 +0200
Processing by Content::MediaController#create as JSON
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

{"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"content/media", "format"=>"json"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: medium:
```

Is the problem in the fact that I format it as json? But shouldnt atleast the text params be passed to the controller?

I cannot use the html Post too because the nature of my application is so that it will intercept all HTML requests when you log in.

Also maybe worth nothing that I use `paperclip` to manage my uploads for me. So I probably have to get the file sent into a proper format too for it?

Comment: As far as I can tell the `data:` key needs to be the contents of the file. To send additional params, you could use the url, for example 

    `url: "/media.json" + '?firstName=Kaspar`

On the server side, the only way I could access the file was using `request.body.read` and the headers with `request.headers['Content-Type']`. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the 'upload right away' pattern.  Here is a complete example for future seekers:

app/views/static-pages/index.html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>

  <h1>StaticPages#index</h1>
  <p>Find me in: app/views/static_pages/index.html.erb</p>
  <hr>

  <div ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl">
    <input type="file" 
      ng-file-select=""
      ng-model='selectedFiles' 
      ng-file-change="myUpload(selectedFiles)" 
      ng-multiple="true">
  </div>

</div>
```

app/assets/javascripts/main.js.coffee:

```
@app = angular.module 'myApp', ['angularFileUpload']
```

app/assets/javascripts/FileUploadCtrl.js.coffee:

```
@app.controller 'FileUploadCtrl', [
  '$scope', 
  '$upload', 
  '$timeout', 
  ($scope, $upload, $timeout) ->

    $scope.myUpload = (files) ->
      len = files.length
      i = 0
      fileReader = undefined
      csrf_token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

      for file in files
        fileReader = new FileReader()

        #-------
        fileReader.onload = (e) ->

          #Define function for timeout, e.g. $timeout(timeout_func, 5000) 
          timeout_func = ->
            file.upload = $upload.http {
              url: "/static_pages/upload",
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': file.type,
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
              },
              data: e.target.result #the file's contents as an ArrayBuffer
            }

            file.upload.then(
              (success_resp) -> file.result = success_resp.data,  #response from server (=upload.html)
              (failure_resp) -> 
                if failure_resp.status > 0
                  $scope.errorMsg = "#{failure_resp.status}: #{response.data}"
            )

            file.upload.progress( (evt) ->
              file.progress = Math.min 100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)
            )
          #end of timeout_func

          $timeout timeout_func, 5000 

        #end of FileReader.onload

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer file
]
```

Note: In the code above, I had to add the csrf lines because in app/views/layouts/application.rb, I have this:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

which causes rails to add a csrf token to each web page.  angular-file-upload was causing `rails CSRF Errors`, so I had to retrieve the csrf token and add it to the request headers.

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//I removed: 
//     require turbolinks 
//for angular app
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//
//The 'require_tree .' adds all the files in some random
//order, but for AngularJS the order is important:
//
//= require angular
//= require angular-file-upload-all
//
//And for some inexplicable reason, this is needed:
//= require main
//I would think 'require_tree .' would be enough for that file.
//
//= require_tree .
```

I didn't use gems for angular or angular-file-upload.  I just copied the AngularJS code into a file named angular.js which I put inside app/assets/javascripts.  Similarly, I copied the code in angular-file-upload-all into app/assets/javascripts/angular-file-upload-all.js

app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def upload
    puts "****PARAMS:"
    p params 

    puts "****body of request: #{request.body.read.inspect}"  #inspect => outputs "" for empty body rather than nothing
    puts "****Content-Type: #{request.headers['Content-Type']}"

    render nothing: true
  end  

end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Test1::Application.routes.draw do
  root "static_pages#index" 
  post "static_pages/upload"
```

As far as I can tell the `data:` key needs to be the contents of the file (as an ArrayBuffer). To get rails to insert additional data in the params hash, you could use the url, for example

```
url: "/media.json" + '?firstName=Kaspar
```

On the server side, the only way I could access the file was using `request.body.read` and the headers with `request.headers['Content-Type']`. What did you end up doing?

#### Also, I found two problems with file.type here:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': file.type,
```

**1) For some reason, neither FireFox nor Chrome can determine the file type of a `.json` file**, so `file.type` ends up being a blank string: `""`.  Rails then enters the file's contents as *a key* in the params hash.  Huh?

If you tack `.json` onto the end of the url:

```
url: "/static_pages/upload.json",
```

...then Rails will parse the body of the request as JSON and enter the key/value pairs in the params hash.  But adding `.json` to the url doesn't make the code very general because it prevents other file types from being processed correctly.

Here is a more general solution for uploading `.json` files:

```
  for file in files
    file_type = file.type

    if file_type is ''  #is => ===
      [..., file_ext] = file.name.split '.'

      if file_ext is 'json' 
        file_type = 'application/json'
```

...then later in the code:

```
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': file_type, #instead of file.type
```

**2)  However, there is still a closure problem** in the original code, which needs to be corrected in order for multiple file selections to work correctly.  If you select multiple files, then the file_type for all the files will end up being the file_type of the last file.  For instance, if you select a `.txt` file and a `.json` file, then both files will have the type of the second file, i.e. `application/json`.  That's problematic because rails will try to parse the body of the text file as JSON, which will produce the error `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError`.

To correct the closure problem, one well known solution is to define a wrapper function around fileReader.onload().  Coffeescript has a syntax that makes adding a wrapper function especially pain free:

```
    do (file_type) ->  #wrapper function, which `do` immediately executes sending it the argument file_type
      fileReader.onload = (e) ->
        ...
        ...
```

By adding one line, you can fix the shared variable problem. For details on what that does, go to the [coffeescript home page](http://coffeescript.org/) and search the page for: `do keyword`.

app/assets/javascripts/FileUploadCtrl.js.coffee:

```
@app.controller 'FileUploadCtrl', [
  '$scope', 
  '$upload', 
  '$timeout', 
  ($scope, $upload, $timeout) ->

    $scope.myUpload = (files) ->
      len = files.length
      i = 0
      fileReader = undefined
      csrf_token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

      for file in files
        #console.log file
        file_type = file.type
        #console.log file_type

        if file_type is '' 
          [..., file_ext] = file.name.split '.'
          #console.log file_ext
          if file_ext is 'json'
            file_type = 'application/json'
            #console.log "Corrected file_type: " + file_type


        fileReader = new FileReader()

        #-------
        do (file_type) ->
          fileReader.onload = (e) ->

            #Define function for timeout, e.g. $timeout(timeout_func, 5000) 
            timeout_func = ->

              file.upload = $upload.http( 
                url: "/static_pages/upload"
                method: 'POST'
                headers: 
                  'Content-Type': file_type 
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
                data: e.target.result, #file contents as ArrayBuffer
              )

              file.upload.then(
                (success_resp) -> file.result = success_resp.data,  #response from server 
                (failure_resp) -> 
                  if failure_resp.status > 0
                    $scope.errorMsg = "#{failure_resp.status}: #{response.data}"
              )

              file.upload.progress (evt) ->
                file.progress = Math.min 100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)
            #end of timeout_func

            $timeout timeout_func, 5000 

          #end of FileReader.onload

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer file
]
```

Finally, in this code,

```
data: e.target.result
```

...the entity returned by `e.target.result` is an `ArrayBuffer`, and I wasn't able to figure out how to modify that to add additional data.

Comment: Well pretty much the same thing happens then also. It send nothing to the server. In my post i show the server log,   the params you see there are the default ones sent. But the data I wanted to send with the data: key, is just not there.

Comment: @Kaspar, I'll take another look at it.

Comment: It seems I managed to get the info to the server now. This angular plugin seemed to have the $http method working in a strange way.